# Rails trying to connect to localhost when rails environment is set to production on Passenger inside Docker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, passenger

I'm trying to deploy a Rails application with Passenger(5.1.2), Nginx and Docker, I have already deployed an Application on a single server without Docker and all succeeded.

The problem I have is, that even when I'm setting the `passenger_app_env`  to production, when starting Nginx, the Rails app is trying to connect to my PostgreSQL on my localhost, but when I access the rails console the connection is successful.

The weirdest thing is that inside my `database.yml` my development credentials and my production credentials have a host that it's not `localhost` but an Amazon RDS

```
 development:

  database:  <%= ENV['POSTGRES_DB_DEV'] %>
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  user: <%= ENV['POSTGRES_USER_DEV'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['POSTGRES_PWD_DEV'] %>
  host: <%= ENV['POSTGRES_HOST_DEV'] %>
  port: <%= ENV['POSTGRES_PORT_DEV'] %>
  pool: <%= ENV['POSTGRES_POOL_DEV'] %>

production:
  database:  <%= ENV['POSTGRES_DB_PROD'] %>
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  user: <%= ENV['POSTGRES_USER_PROD'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['POSTGRES_PWD_PROD'] %>
  host: <%= ENV['POSTGRES_HOST_PROD'] %>
  port: <%= ENV['POSTGRES_PORT_PROD'] %>
  pool: <%= ENV['POSTGRES_POOL_PROD'] %>
```

The corresponding variables for the hosts are:

```
xxxxx.xxxx.xx-xxx.rds.amazonaws.com
```

Here are the environment variables that Passenger sets when starting the application:

```
GEM_HOME = /opt/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2
SHELL = /usr/sbin/nologin
IRBRC = /opt/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/.irbrc
PYTHONUNBUFFERED = 1
PASSENGER_DEBUG_DIR = /tmp/passenger.spawn-debug.XXXX7Po96m
MY_RUBY_HOME = /opt/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2
USER = nobody
IN_PASSENGER = 1
RACK_ENV = production
PASSENGER_USE_FEEDBACK_FD = true
PATH = /opt/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin:/opt/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/bin:/opt/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:.
WSGI_ENV = production
PWD = /api
NODE_PATH = /usr/share/passenger/node
NODE_ENV = production
SHLVL = 0
HOME = /nonexistent
RAILS_ENV = production
LOGNAME = nobody
SERVER_SOFTWARE = nginx/1.10.2 Phusion_Passenger/5.1.2
GEM_PATH = /opt/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2:/opt/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global
PASSENGER_APP_ENV = production
RUBY_VERSION = ruby-2.1.2
BUNDLER_ORIG_PATH = /opt/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin:/opt/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/bin:/opt/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:.
BUNDLER_ORIG_GEM_PATH = /opt/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2:/opt/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global
BUNDLE_BIN_PATH = /opt/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/bundler-1.14.6/exe/bundle
BUNDLE_GEMFILE = /Befective/api/Gemfile
BUNDLER_VERSION = 1.14.6
RUBYOPT = -rbundler/setup
RUBYLIB = /opt/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib
```

Nginx Configuration file for the site:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    passenger_enabled on;
    passenger_app_env production;
    passenger_max_request_queue_size 2000;
    passenger_ruby /opt/rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.1.2/ruby;
    root /api/public;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

}
```

Error passenger raises:

```
could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
 (PG::ConnectionBad)
  /opt/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `initialize'
  /opt/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `new'
  /opt/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `connect'
  /opt/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:242:in `initialize'
  /opt/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:44:in `new'
  /opt/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:44:in `postgresql_connection'
  /opt/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:438:in `new_connection'
  /opt/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:448:in `checkout_new_connection'
  /opt/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:422:in `acquire_connection'
  /opt/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:349:in `block in checkout'
  /opt/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
  /opt/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:348:in `checkout'
  /opt/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:263:in `block in connection'
  /opt/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
  /opt/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:262:in `connection'
  /opt/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:571:in `retrieve_connection'
  /opt/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.7/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve_connection'
  /opt/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.7/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:87:in `connection'
  /Befective/api/config/initializers/apartment.rb:23:in `block in <top (required)>'
  /opt/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/apartment-1.1.0/lib/apartment.rb:24:in `configure'
  /Befective/api/config/initializers/apartment.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
  /opt/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
  /opt/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
  /opt/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
  /opt/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
  /opt/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.2.7/lib/rails/engine.rb:652:in `block in load_config_initializer'
  /opt/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.7/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
  /opt/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.2.7/lib/rails/engine.rb:651:in `load_config_initializer'
  /opt/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.2.7/lib/rails/engine.rb:616:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
  /opt/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.2.7/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `each'
  /opt/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.2.7/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `block in <class:Engine>'
  /opt/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.2.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
  /opt/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.2.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
  /opt/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.2.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
  /opt/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
  /opt/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
  /opt/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:418:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
  /opt/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:427:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
  /opt/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:417:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
  /opt/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.2.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
  /opt/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.2.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
  /opt/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:411:in `call'
  /opt/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:411:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
  /opt/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
  /opt/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
  /opt/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
  /opt/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
  /opt/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
  /opt/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
  /opt/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.2.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
  /opt/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.2.7/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
  /Befective/api/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
  config.ru:3:in `require'
  config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
  /opt/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
  /opt/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
  config.ru:1:in `new'
  config.ru:1:in `<main>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:110:in `eval'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:110:in `preload_app'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:156:in `<module:App>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:30:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<main>'
```

Even if I enter the docker itself and execute the rails server command it executes successfully.

*** EDIT ****

So I have managed to reach a point where I know what's causing this bug, but now I don't know how to solve that problem now, it seems to be that after initializing the Rails app `Rails.application.initialize!` all of the environment variables are not set correctly, I did set the `DATABASE_URL` env variable to test this behavior and printed all of the variables after initializing the Rails app inside `environment.rb`, and the env variable `DATABASE_URL` is missing, file:

```
#environment.rb

Rails.application.initialize!
raise "#{ENV.to_h.to_s}"
```

Result:

```
  Message from application: true {"development"=>{"database"=>nil, "adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "user"=>nil, "password"=>nil, "host"=>nil, "port"=>nil, "pool"=>nil}, "production"=>{"database"=>nil, "adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "user"=>nil, "password"=>nil, "host"=>nil, "port"=>nil, "pool"=>nil}}, {"GEM_HOME"=>"/opt/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2", "SHELL"=>"/usr/sbin/nologin", "IRBRC"=>"/opt/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/.irbrc", "PYTHONUNBUFFERED"=>"1", "PASSENGER_DEBUG_DIR"=>"/tmp/passenger.spawn-debug.XXXXS4Y1Ah", "MY_RUBY_HOME"=>"/opt/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2", "USER"=>"www-data", "IN_PASSENGER"=>"1", "RACK_ENV"=>"production", "PASSENGER_USE_FEEDBACK_FD"=>"true", "PATH"=>"/opt/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin:/opt/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/bin:/opt/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:.", "WSGI_ENV"=>"production", "PWD"=>"/Befective/api", "NODE_PATH"=>"/usr/share/passenger/node", "NODE_ENV"=>"production", "SHLVL"=>"0", "HOME"=>"/var/www", "RAILS_ENV"=>"production", "LOGNAME"=>"www-data", "SERVER_SOFTWARE"=>"nginx/1.10.2 Phusion_Passenger/5.1.2", "GEM_PATH"=>"/opt/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2:/opt/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global", "PASSENGER_APP_ENV"=>"production", "RUBY_VERSION"=>"ruby-2.1.2", "BUNDLER_ORIG_PATH"=>"/opt/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin:/opt/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/bin:/opt/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:.", "BUNDLER_ORIG_GEM_PATH"=>"/opt/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2:/opt/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global", "BUNDLE_BIN_PATH"=>"/opt/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/bundler-1.14.6/exe/bundle", "BUNDLE_GEMFILE"=>"/Befective/api/Gemfile", "BUNDLER_VERSION"=>"1.14.6", "RUBYOPT"=>"-rbundler/setup", "RUBYLIB"=>"/opt/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib"}
```

Comment: I would make sure you are attempting to connect to RDS using `https` and not a unix socket.

Comment: @CWitty I don't think that matters, because as I said, when I access the console with: bundle exec rails c it connects succesfully

Comment: You can remove all that cruft in your database.yml by using ENV["DATABASE_URL"] instead of 5+ vars. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database

Comment: @max I will take that into account but I think it's not related to the problem, because the DATABASE_URL env variable is not set on docker, so passenger and rails should respect the connection inside database.yml

Comment: What does `Rails.env` give you? If its not production then it could be that RAILS_ENV is not set properly.

Comment: @max On the Code Snippets I pasted above RAILS_ENV is set to production, executing Rails.env gives production too: 

2.1.2 :003 > Rails.env
 => "production" 

ActiveRecord::Base.configurations (which brings theCConfiguration of the database) brings the next on the hosts:  

 => {"development"=>{ "adapter"=>"postgresql", "host"=>"xxxxxxxx.rds.amazonaws.com", "port"=>5432}, "production"=>{"adapter"=>"postgresql","host"=>"xxxxxxxxx-.rds.amazonaws.com", "port"=>5432,}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after spending some hours with this bug I have finally managed to beat it!

According to the [nginx documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#env):

> By default, nginx removes all environment variables inherited from its
>   parent process except the TZ variable. This directive allows
>   preserving some of the inherited variables, changing their values, or
>   creating new environment variables.

That's why any environment variables you set with `docker run -e` won't reach Nginx.

To preserve these variables, place an Nginx config file ending with `*.conf` in the directory `/etc/nginx/main.d`, in which you tell Nginx to preserve these variables, and then reference these files inside `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` by adding `include /etc/nginx/main.d/*.conf;`

Comment: hi sir,can u please share syntax for preserving env variable inside *conf file